# Ruby on Rails key ActiveRecord result set into hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a trivial ActiveRecord query that looks like the following in my Ruby on Rails 4 application:

```
ps = PlayerSalary.where(gamedate: date, site_id: site.id).find_all_by_player_id(player_ids)
```

My question is the following. the `ps` set could have a couple hundred records at any given time, normally up to 300. I want to be able to be able to access a record from it when I loop over `player_ids` like the following:

```
player_ids.each do |pid|
  # retrieve record from `ps` where ps.player_id == pid
end
```

The fastest way to do that would be to organize the `ps` set up by hash where the key is the `player_id`. What's the best way to create that hash from `ps`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply go over the list, and create a map:

```
ps_map = {}
ps.each do |p|
  ps_map[p.player_id] = p
end
```

Answer (score 4):

In one line:

`ps.each_with_object({}) { |r, h| h[r.id] = r }`

Answer (score 3):

## Ruby 2.1+

```
ps_ids_hash = ps.map{ |c| [c.name,c.code] }.to_h
```

## Ruby 1.8.7+

```
ps_ids_hash = Hash[ ps.map{ |c| [c.name,c.code] } ]
```

## Ruby 1.8.6+

```
ps_ids_hash = Hash[ *ps.map{ |p| [p.id,p] }.flatten ]
```

## Ruby 1.9+

```
ps_ids_hash = {}.tap{ |h| ps.each{ |p| h[p.id] = p } }
```

## Ruby 1.9+

```
ps_ids_hash = ps.to_a.each_with_object({}){ |p,h| h[p.id] = p }
```

## Ruby 1.8+

```
ps_ids_hash = ps.inject({}){ |r,p| r.merge p.id => p }
```

Comment: In Rails 4, you can do something which serves your purpose
Hash[*ps.pluck(:id), *ps]

Answer (score 1):

Uri Agassi's (revised) answer should work. This will get the same result in a way that I prefer.

```
Hash[ ps.map{ |p| [p.player_id, p] } ]
```